# Usage of the word "it" in the sentence "it wasn't me"

Tags: pronouns

What does ***it*** refer to in the sentence

> It wasn't me.

For example in response to the question

> Who stole the cookies?

I see "***it***" as referring to the person who stole the cookies, but it doesn't sound right to say "***he wasn't me***" or "***she wasn't me***".

Can anyone clear this up for me

Comment: I'd say that the interpretation of "it" is given by the preceding clause. "Who stole the cookies?" ~ "It was x who stole the cookies" ~ "I'm not x".

Comment: Similarly, "Someone spoke to me. It was the girl I saw earlier."

Comment: _It_ does not refer in this construction. It is an invariable dummy pronoun.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this case, "it" refers to a person. Usually in English we refer to people as "he" or "she", but we use "it" when referring back to a person just mentioned in a sentence using a form of "to be". Like, "Who put this on my desk?" "It was Bob." Or, "Someone stole my coffee cup!" "Yes, it was Sally." You might think that it would be more consistent to say, "He was Bob" and "She was Sally". But we don't.

"It" can also refer back to some event just described. Like, "What caused XYZ Corporation to go bankrupt?" "It was bad management." Here "it" is referring to "the event that caused the company to go bankrupt".

Sometimes "it" is used as a kind of dummy placeholder. Like, "It is raining today." What is raining? Well, we're not really thinking of some THING that is raining. We're just saying that that's what's happening.

Comment: "Bobby is it you?, asked Julie after hearing a loud noise in the kitchen" is another example. I think that it's more correct to say that 'it' is a placeholder, than that it refers to a person. We don't know yet if who or what made the noise is Bobby, Mary, a cat, the wind or Michael Myers.

Comment: @GrandTorini Plausible. Maybe my "unknown person" and "some event" are really the same case. I didn't base my answer on anything I read in a grammar book but rather on my interpretation with experience speaking the language for 60 years. Grammar experts may well have "cleaner" definitions.

Comment: @GrandTorini BTW your answer reminds me ... In the past year I've gone from having 4 people living in my house to just me. A few days ago I was downstairs and I heard some floorboards creaking upstairs, and I said to myself, "My daughter must be walking around up there." Then I realized she no longer lived here. So, I concluded, it must be either a burglar or a ghost. That is, "it" in this case could be a person, a ghost, or something truly boring like changing temperatures.

Comment: @GrandTorini I think it refers to any entity or possible cause of the action. So in your example the "it" refers to whatever the cause of the noise is. And in my example, "it" is an unknown person as it is in response to the question "who xxx?" which means the answer is expected to be a person

Comment: @ShayBoual I agree, I was thinking in general terms. I believe that "it" is a just a neutral placeholder that can be anything, he/ she/ it. That can also apply to your example, e.g. "Who stole the cookies?" "It wasn't me, it was the cat!" ...